# How can I connect to my MySQL container from Spring Boot (java.net.UnknownHostException)?

Tags: spring, docker

I am new to Docker and I am trying to set up two containers for my [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) application and MySQL database.
I can run the MySQL container, but the application container fails because it cannot connect to MySQL due to *Unknown host*.

This is my [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29#Tools) file:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    image: my-custom-image
    container_name: spring-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - 'local-network'
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb


  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.28-oracle
    container_name: mysqldb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mysql-db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    networks:
      - 'local-network'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - case-mysql-data:/var/lib/case-mysqldb
      - ./mysql-db-dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-db-dump.sql:ro

volumes:
  case-mysql-data:

networks:
  local-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile for the Spring application

```
FROM maven:3.8.8-eclipse-temurin-17 AS Builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn clean package


FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=Builder /app/target/*.jar /app/application.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]
```

#### File *application.properties*

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/mysql-db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

When I build these with `docker-compose up --build`, the MySQL container works fine, but the Spring container cannot connect to it, giving the error:

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mysqldb: Name or service not known.

I know that there are similar questions but none of them solved my problem.

I checked the networks and containers are running in the same network. I can also connect to the MySQL container through [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) when the Spring application is running locally, but it fails when I try to run it in the container and change the host name to my MySQL service. I looked at several examples and tried changing the host name, but nothing worked.

Is there anything wrong with my setup?

Comment: You bridge your network with a custom bridge. Try it without that and see what happens.

Comment: I tried it now but still the same error :/. I can run these containers with docker compose up and can ping the 'mysqldb' from the app container. But it runs the previous version of the app where I did not establish a connection to the database. It fails when I try to build.

Comment: I would try and use `host.docker.internal` as that hostname is always configured as default `0.0.0.0` in docker's internal network. More information [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)

Answer (score -1):

Try to sleep until the MySQL server is running and up.

```
services:
 app:
  image: my-custom-image
  container_name: spring-app
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - '8080:8080'
  networks:
   - 'local-network'
  depends_on:
   - mysqldb
  command: >
   sh -c "sleep 60"
```

Comment: The `command:` runs _instead of_ the normal container command; this causes the container to sleep for 60 seconds and then exit, without running the application.  In any case a fixed-duration delay isn't usually the preferred approach here.  If you think the problem is that the database isn't ready yet (and it may be) please flag this as a duplicate of [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y).

Comment: Re *"running and up"*: Do you mean *"[up and running](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/up_and_running#Adjective)"* (not a rhetorical question)?